# How to start learn SharePoint

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-online, sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-foundation, sharepoint-server

As a newbie  to SharePoint I'm looking for your suggestion for getting some

1. good learning sites
2. good blogs
3. communities to discuss
4. And if you don't mind kindly share your experience.

I'm expecting to get the answers from your experiences which will be helpful for many newcomers in this field that how you people have started.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Welcome to the interesting path of SharePoint. As mentioned on another answer, search engines are your best friend to find the exact help for your need. Even the simplest questions, but also the more complex ones tend to be answered elsewhere so hopefully your knowledge searching skills are already up there.

I have nothing to add to the [Aakash Morya's](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/users/52649/aakash-morya) links in his answer for how to get started, so moving along:

2. Good blogs in no order:

   - [Bamboo Nation community](http://community.bamboosolutions.com/blogs/) - a wide range of blog posts from the very basics to customized app development
   - [Russ Maxwell's MSDN blog](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/russmax/) - for SharePoint administrator who likes PowerShell
   - [Tobias Zimmergren's blog](https://zimmergren.net/) - a blog focusing on more advanced development of SharePoint
   - [Jussi Palo's blog](http://blog.jussipalo.com/) - a plentiful toolbox covering all-round administrator's duties
   - [Benjamin Niaulin's blog](https://bniaulin.wordpress.com/) - Product Evangelist of Share-gate hasn't been blogging on this site lately, but the site still provides various detailed guides
   - [Randy Drisgill's blog](http://blog.drisgill.com/) - one of the SharePoint blogs focusing on branding & designing
   - [Waldyk Mastykarz's blog](https://blog.mastykarz.nl) - one more development focused blog
   - [Learning SharePoint blog](http://www.learningsharepoint.com/author/ikapoor/) - an active blog with detailed guides for various cases
   - [Erik Swenson's blog](http://erikswenson.blogspot.com) - apparently discontinued branding & designing blog with several pretty guides
   - [Elio Struyf's blog](https://www.eliostruyf.com/) - a more all-round blog from front-end to back-end
   - [Lixyan0125's blog](https://lixuan0125.wordpress.com/) - a more unknown blog focusing on backend development
   - [Steve Chen's blog](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/steve_chen/) and [Stefan Goßner's blog](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/stefan_gossner/) - both focusing on SharePoint updates you should be aware of

And that's just to name few. You are very likely to find your own favorite blog during your learning process just by spotting who has posted the most helpful posts concerning your questions.

3. I'd only mention two here:

   - [The site we are in](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com)
   - [Social.Technet.Microsoft.com](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/sharepoint/en-US/home) - Several Microsoft employees are available here, so to e.g. follow bug cases this might be at its best
4. Just few words from my own experience: I got to know SharePoint by having a pre-installed environment having no production sites. I was given a task to develop a site collection with several features so I had to at first see what can be done out-of-the-box (the least time consuming) and which required further development (more time consuming). I'd suggest to

   - try every web part and app on your test site,
   - go through every settings you can find and try to figure out what are they meant for,
   - move on to what you are supposed to do

E.g. if your task is to create a project site or a document approval tool, search on search engines how others have done it and mimic them. There are usually best practices and there are the simple ways to do it.

Last words would be that with SharePoint you definitely learn by doing.

Comment: If I would have asked the question then I will mark this answer as accepted and qualitative. It will really helpful to new comers in SharePoint

Comment: Both the answers are helpful!

Answer (score 2):

There are bunch of resources available on internet to learn SharePoint, If you just type the same question "**Learn SharePoint**" on any search engine you will get the links and communities there itself.

Still few of them are

- [Learn SharePoint - Step-by-Step | Free](http://sharepoint-tutorial.net/page/learn-sharepoint.aspx)
- [Learning SharePoint - Let's Talk about the Basics](http://en.share-gate.com/blog/start-learn-sharepoint-basics)
- [Getting Started with SharePoint 2010 Development–Links and
  Resources](http://blogs.msmvps.com/windsor/2011/08/01/getting-started-with-sharepoint-2010-development-links-and-resources/)

The best ever link from where you can learn SharePoint in detail level is [SharePoint](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc303422.aspx). This is my all time favorite link. It contain the details regarding all versions of SharePoint.

Comment: Thanks for the reply!as you said,I had come across various sites and blogs but  I was really confused to follow those.I wanted to follow something which gives real time idea about the project implementation in SharePoint.

Comment: this https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc303422.aspx would really give you a great conceptual learning